# components conflicts with toolbar and pickerview

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uipickerview, uitoolbar

In my app I am showing uipicker view with toolbar . But when it appears it is conflict with other components.

[image]

Here "Select Establishment" is label with frame and "remove" is button and also "add sign" is button.
"Done" is inside toolbar and after toolbar it is uipickerview

So I want when toolbar and picker view appear it should hide that things

Comment: post a larger picture. also... i don't see any pickerView.

Comment: your picker view is behind those view in view hierarchy. U can move your picker view to the foremost in your view hierarchy to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your picker and toolbar are underneath other UI elements.

One way to change this is by doing something like this -

```
// put where you present your picker to test
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myPickerView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myToolBar];
```

If they are set up in interface builder you can also optionally select and drag them in the appropriate order in the left hand sidebar where they appear under place holders, files owner, first responder.

If you want to hide UI elements completely set their **hidden** property to **YES** and NO to unhide.